# Extract icon from Mono executable

Tags: icons, mono

I am running Mono executables from the Launch panel in Gnome, but I can't set the right icon. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the same tools Colin mentioned. First install the `icoutils` package. Then to extract the ico from dlls or exe, just run:

```
wrestool -x --output=. -t14 name.exe
```

That usually extracts the main icon. Then to convert the ico file to png run:

```
for i in *.ico; do convert "$i" "$i.png"; done
```

The first command works for me about 99% of the time. If it doesn't give you the right icon file you can check this more in depth [tutorial](http://jamesmcdonald.id.au/it-tips/gnu-linux/how-to-extract-icons-from-windows-executeables-in-linux). Also, you can use the [wrestool man file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/wrestool.1.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to only work with 32bit (or 16bit) .exe files. wrestool cannot find resources in 64bit .exe files.

Answer (score 5):

Try the `wrestool` utility in the `icoutils` package - I believe it can extract icon resources from Mono executables.